# Is there any way to get an HTML page rendered through Chrome/Chromium from a console?

Tags: ssh, html, chrome

Is there any way to get (into a file, for example) a rendered HTML page from Google Chrome/Chromium, but from a console. For example, SSHed into a machine that has Chrome/Chromium installed on Debian/Ubuntu. I want to be able to see the page from the console, but with all Javascripts executed and for example some JSON data parsed/rendered.

Comment: From the console? you mean like with an framebuffer? doubtful? what are you trying to do? perhaps something like selenium webdriver might help. Also you might want to look at webkit/v8 more directly rather than the chrome implementation.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to take a look at the [Uzbl browser](http://uzbl.org/).

It's a minimalist web browser based on webkit (the layout engine used by Chrome/Chromium). According to the definition, it's a collection of *"web interface tools which adhere to the unix philosophy".*

It comes in 3 flavors:

- uzbl-core
- uzbl-browser
- uzbl-tabbed

The latter 2 are finished products and  probably won't do what you're looking for. However the first one (`uzbl-core`) is a nice wrapper around webkit and should fit the case you described.